# Aspectj, how to use ajc in a modular way

Tags: osgi, aspectj, modularity, bnd

I am trying to use the Aspectj compiler [ajc](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html) in a modular (OSGi setting). The standard way ajc seems to be used is to take aspects & java code and turn it into one a JAR with *all* classes and resources in the `-inpath`, `-aspectpath`, and `-sourceroots`.

I am trying to *weave* aspects an OSGi executable JAR from bnd. This executable jar contains a set of bundles that need to be woven. However, in a modular system, the boundary is quite important. For one, the manifest often contains highly relevant information to that bundle or one of the many *extenders*. Flattening all the classes into a big blog won't work.

I am therefore weaving each bundle separately. However, then the output is cluttered with the aspects. I'd like to  import these to keep the aspect modules proper modules. However, using the annotation programming model, I notice that ajc is modifying the aspect modules, so I need to rewrite those as well. This is fine, but since I weave each bundle separately, I have the question if the weaving of the *aspect* could depend on what gets other modules woven? That is,
does the modification of the annotated *aspect* depend on the classes that it is woven in?

The other issue is what happens to resources with the same name? Since my `-inpath` is only one JAR (the bundle), I notice I end up with the correct manifest (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) in the output. However, if the `-inpath` consists of many bundles, what will the manifest be? Or any other resource that has the same path and thus overlaps?

Last issue is external dependencies. I understand acj wants to see the whole world and include this whole world into the output JAR. However, I must exclude external dependencies of a bundle. Is there a way to mark JARs as: use, but do not include. A bit like the maven 'provided' scope?

Summary:

- Does the modification of an @Aspect annotated class depend on the targets that is applied to?
- Can I compile the @Aspect annotated classes into separate JARs?
- How to handle the external dependencies that will be *provided* in the runtime and thus must be excluded from the output JAR.
- What are the rules around overlapping resource paths in the `-inpath` and `-sourceroots`?

**UPDATE** In the mean time I've made an [implementation in Bndtools](https://bnd.bndtools.org/plugins/aspectj.html).

Comment: Peter, this is a very interesting topic, but the fact that it contains several questions at once instead of just one clear question with a clear answer makes answering hard. I am afraid that this format would fit a discussion forum or a mailing list such as aspectj-users better than SO. I am not an OSGi user, but I do basically understand some of your questions. I think that an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample project on GitHub, illustrating all of your questions, would be tremendously helpful in order to reproduce your pain points. Then I could maybe try and answer here.

Comment: I am not sure how to make a viable project. I've implemented this in [bndtools][1]. However, I am not sure if I can _rely_ on the observed behavior. As far as I can see the processing model of Aspectj is very much the flat class path and the documentation does not discuss all the potential issues that this causes. As often in Java, it generally works :-) However, in the OSGi world we need more formal specs since we try to detect the problems up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the modification of an @Aspect annotated class depend on the targets that is applied to?

If you want to be 100% sure you have to read the AspectJ source code, but I would assume that an aspect's byte code is independent of its target classes, because otherwise you could not compile aspects separately and also not build aspect libraries.

> Can I compile the @Aspect annotated classes into separate JARs?

Absolutely, see above.

> How to handle the external dependencies that will be *provided* in the runtime and thus must be excluded from the output JAR.

If I understand the question correctly, you probably want to put them on the class path during compilation, not on the inpath.

> What are the rules around overlapping resource paths in the `-inpath` and `-sourceroots`?

Again, probably you have to look at the source code. If I was you I would simply assume that the selection order is undefined and make sure to not have duplicates in the first place. There should be Maven plugins helping you with filtering the way **you** want the result to be.

---

*bndtools* seems to have close ties to Eclipse. So does AspectJ as an Eclipse project. Maybe you can connect with Andy Clement, the AspectJ maintainer. He is so swamped with his day-time job though, he hardly ever has any free cycles. I am trying to unburden him as much as I can, but OSGi is one of my blind spots and I hardly know the AspectJ source code. I am rather an advanced user.

Comment: Thanks! About the provided scope, are you saying that -classpath JARs are visible to the aspectpath & inpath code? BTW, this is an OSGi problem but you would run into the same problems in a JPMS world. It is a modularity problem.

Comment: If we are talking about compilation, yes. What is on the compilation classpath is also visible to all of sourceroots, inpath and aspectpath code. Everything from sourceroots and inpath will be aspect-woven and written to the output directory. Aspectpath and classpath classes will not be woven and not be written, which explains why the latter two need to be on the runtime classpath again.